# How don't use Gnus adaptive scoring in some newsgroups?

Tags: email, emacs

If I do:

```
(setq gnus-use-adaptive-scoring t)
```

The adaptive scoring works properly, but for all groups.

Then I tried this, but without success:

```
(setq gnus-parameters
  '(("mail\\..*"
     (gnus-use-adaptive-scoring nil))
    ("gmane\\..*"
     (gnus-use-adaptive-scoring t))))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears to work for me.  I used this setting:

```
(setq gnus-parameters 
  '(("regressions.*"
     (gnus-use-adaptive-scoring nil))
    ("general-personal.*"
     (gnus-use-adaptive-scoring t))))
```

Perhaps your regexps don't match your group names?  The above regexps will match groups that look like `mail.` and `gmane.` (the `.` being a real period).

The way I tested it was to enter each of the two groups and did an eval on the variable `M-: gnus-use-adaptive-scoring RET` - though you could also just do help on the variable `C-h v gnus-use-adaptive-scoring RET`.

Perhaps what you want is not to turn **adaptive**-scoring off, but just to turn scoring off.  AFAIK, adaptive-scoring is Gnus trying to *figure* *out* scoring for the articles, but not the actual **use** of scoring.

So maybe this does what you want?

```
(setq gnus-parameters 
  '(("mail\\..*"
     (gnus-use-scoring nil))
    ("gmane\\..*"
     (gnus-use-scoring t))))
```

Comment: Hi, the settings really works, the value of gnus-use-adaptive-scoring on mail.* groups is nil, but in practice, the adaptive scoring on these groups is on.

Comment: I don't use scoring myself, so this may be off the mark (hard to test w/out a history of scoring).  But, I've added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put `(adapt nil)` in the score file of all the groups where you do not want adaptative scoring activated, and you can use topics to set up a common score file for a bunch of groups, as described [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScoreFile#toc3).